How to find a 4 byte value in a memory dump in gdb or macro
How to compare a value contained in a memory address in a process with a known value in GDB macro.
set $_start = (char*)$arg0
set $_end = (char*)$addr + $size
while (u_int32_t)$_start != (u_int32_t)$_end
    set $_val = *(u_int32_t*)$_start
    if (u_int32_t)$_val == (u_int32_t)$arg1
        printf "value found"
        loop_break
    end
    set $_start = $_start + 4
end

When I run this macro I get an error:
(gdb) check_address_reference 0x1be00b28 0x1be00b90
Debug enabled: 1
Undefined command: "$_start".  Try "help".

The way we can do it in the gdb shell
(gdb) p/x *(unsigned int*)0x1be00b40
$15 = 0x1be00b90


Note: looks like an endless loop if $size == 1.

@ikegami updated

size is guranteed to be greater than equal to 16

Try the find command.

Why don't you use u_int32_t* for $_start and $_end in the first place? casting the address to (u_int32_t) in the while statement looks wrong. You will downcast a 64 bit address to a 32 bit integer. Using the right type for the pointers should simplify the increment. As condition for the while loop I would always use < rather than !=.
gdb provides a built-in python interpreter. To find 23 in an int array[50] I can use: print ([i for i in range(50) if gdb.parse_and_eval("array")[i]==23]). It should be simple to parameterize such expression for your usecase.

I will suggest the "in gdb" option. First, I would determine how to dump the region of interest to the terminal while running gdb. There are two options I can think of for this.

Read the Examining Memory page in the GDB manual (or just search "examining memory in gdb"). This can dump a memory region as different sized types such as bytes, half words, words, etc.
Cast a section of memory to your desired type as you have shown with the additional detail of specifying how many units of your type to print. This can be done as follows: p/x ((unsigned int *)0x1be00b40)[0]@5, where the array subscript is the starting element and the number after the @ sign is the number of values to be extended for viewing.

Once you have decided how to view the region you are interested in I would simply use the pipe capabilities of gdb to search for the four byte word you are interested in.
Depending on your choices, a command like this might work.
>>> pipe [DUMP COMMAND YOU HAVE CHOSEN] | grep [4 BYTE WORD]

